# Keras Functional API and loss function with multiple inputs

Tags: function, tensorflow, keras, loss

I am trying to use a custom Keras loss function that apart from the usual  signature `(y_true, y_pred)` takes another parameter `sigma` (which is also produced by the last layer of the network).
The training works fine, but then I am not sure how to perform forward propagation and return `sigma` (while `mu`is the output of the `model.predict` method).
This is the code I am using, which features a custom layer `GaussianLayer` that returns the list `[mu, sigma]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Layer, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.initializers import glorot_normal
import numpy as np

def custom_loss(sigma):
    def gaussian_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(0.5*tf.log(sigma) + 0.5*tf.div(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), sigma)) + 10
    return gaussian_loss

class GaussianLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(GaussianLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel_1 = self.add_weight(name='kernel_1', 
                                      shape=(30, self.output_dim),
                                      initializer=glorot_normal(),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.kernel_2 = self.add_weight(name='kernel_2', 
                                      shape=(30, self.output_dim),
                                      initializer=glorot_normal(),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias_1 = self.add_weight(name='bias_1',
                                    shape=(self.output_dim, ),
                                    initializer=glorot_normal(),
                                    trainable=True)
        self.bias_2 = self.add_weight(name='bias_2',
                                    shape=(self.output_dim, ),
                                    initializer=glorot_normal(),
                                    trainable=True)
        super(GaussianLayer, self).build(input_shape) 

    def call(self, x):
        output_mu  = K.dot(x, self.kernel_1) + self.bias_1
        output_sig = K.dot(x, self.kernel_2) + self.bias_2
        output_sig_pos = K.log(1 + K.exp(output_sig)) + 1e-06  
        return [output_mu, output_sig_pos]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return [(input_shape[0], self.output_dim), (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)]

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(30, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(30, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(40, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(30, activation='relu')(x)
mu, sigma = GaussianLayer(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs, mu)
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(sigma), optimizer='adam')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your model returns two tensors as output, you also need to pass **a list of two arrays** as the output when calling `fit()` method. That's essentially what the error is trying to convey:

> Error when checking **model target**:

So the error is in targets (i.e. labels). What is wrong?

> the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model **is not the size the model expected**. **Expected** to see **2 array(s)**, but instead **got** the following list of **1 arrays**:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to reproduce with Keras [this](https://github.com/vvanirudh/deep-ensembles-uncertainty/blob/master/model.py) Tensorflow implementation `MLPGaussianRegressor `. This entails passing y_true (a single scalar) to the loss function, while y_pred is a list of 2 elements. Sorry, maybe I am approaching this in the wrong way

Comment: @Alberto I didn't looked at that implementation but if your model outputs two tensors (or two scalars) then `y_true` should also be two arrays which you would pass to `fit()` method. Otherwise, you need to change the implementation of your model (either by modifying the implementation of the custom layer or adding other layers to the model) to make it have only one output.

Comment: thanks', I have updated the question with relevant details!

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer among [Keras FAQs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).
I found out that it is possible to retrieve intermediate steps' output using the code snippet below:

```
layer_name = 'main_output'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(train_x[0])
intermediate_output
```

In this case `intermediate_output` is a list of two values `[mu, sigma]` (just needed to name the output layer `main_output` and retrieve it later)